# How to use the git stash command using the stash name to drop, apply and pop?

Tags: bash, git

I would like to find a way to use the git stash command to drop, apply and pop using the stash name (or part of its name) and not only by using its index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to share this with the community since I searched a long time for this until I found the answer so I thought I'd post it here by answering my own question for anybody in the future who needs this.

Here is the answer:

Using bash to set the stash name variable with a value:
`STASH_NAME="stash_name"`

1. **create a stash with a name:**
   *Prior to git version 2.15/2.16 you could only use `git stash save`:*

```
git stash save $STASH_NAME
```

*After git version 2.15/2.16 you could still use `git stash save` although it is considered legacy and deprecated (although still supported) but instead you should use `git stash push`:*

```
git stash push -m $STASH_NAME
```

2. **drop a stash by name of the stash:**

```
git stash drop stash@{$((git stash list | grep -w $STASH_NAME) | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1)}
```

3. **apply a stash by name of the stash:**

```
git stash apply stash^{/$STASH_NAME}
```

4. **pop a stash (apply + delete) by name of the stash:**

```
git stash pop stash@{$((git stash list | grep -w $STASH_NAME) | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1)}
```

Comment: `git stash save` [is deprecated](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#Documentation/git-stash.txt-save-p--patch-S--staged-k--no-keep-index-u--include-untracked-a--all-q--quietltmessagegt)

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund thanks for the comment. I updated the answer accordingly.